# MVC routing and parameter passing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I know it's a basic question, but I am not sure where is my issue. I've created a routing like the following:

```
        routes.MapRoute
        (
            name: "Searching",
            url: "Search/{para1}/{para2}/{para3}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Search",
                action = "Index",
                para1= 0,
                para2= 0,
                para3= 0
            });

    public ActionResult Index(int para1, int para2, int para3)
    {
        ViewBag.para1= para1;
        ViewBag.para2= para2;
        ViewBag.para3= para3;
        return View();
    }
```

By my understanding if I pass a link http://domain.my/search/1/0/1 it should open the given action with the parameters, assigning them as per the order in the request, but in my case I am receiving a 404 error.

Am I mistaking the way that parameters work with the routing or is it some other issue? As I read what I found through google that should be correct, but I am not sure where is my error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems fine to me. Check your controller name.

Comment: Everything works as long as I don't enter any parameters. if the link I enter is  http://domain.my/search/ it works great, but when I provide the parameters it just gets broken.

Comment: It seems fine to me as well.